# Sending form data to spring controller using dojo

Tags: json, spring, dojo

I've a list of records and want to update one. When I click on one, it show a form with all input fields which are already populated using JsonRest. I've edited the fields and now I want to send it to server for updating.
How can I send an Object with dojo?

I tried like this, but at the controller side the value is null.

```
on(dom.byId("poolForm"), "submit", function(evt) {
            var formObj = domForm.toObject("poolForm");
            console.log(formObj);

            request.post("/path/to/EditSubmit", {
                data : formObj,
                method : "POST"
            }). then(function(data) {
                console.log("data");
            });
 });
```

In spring I used:

```
public void editedForm(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody  MyClass myClass) {
    poolParam.getAdd();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating a new record and not updating one, you can use method `add(object, options)` for your `JsonRest`.

Example:

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function(JsonRest){
  // your store
  var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "/some/resource"
  });

  // add an object passing an id
  store.add({
    foo: "foo"
  }, {
    id: 1
  });
});
```

More informations can be found at [JsonRest API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest) and [JsonRest guide](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html).

---

**EDIT:**

As for your comment request, in case you would like to send an object using `dojo/request/xhr` instead of `JsonRest`, you can use the following example, basically:

- Use `dojo/dom-form` utility, to get out values from your form. This utility function will return an object. [More info here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-form.html).
- Use `dojo/request/xhr` to send via Ajax the object previously retrieved from `dojo/dom-form`, this is the data sent to the server. [More info here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html).

Quick demo here:

https://jsbin.com/mocoxuhotu/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script data-dojo-config="async: 1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "dojo/query",
            "dojo/dom-form",
            "dojo/request/xhr",
            "dijit/registry",
            "dijit/form/Form",
            "dojo/parser",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function (
            query,
            domForm,
            xhr,
            registry,
            Form,
            parser
            ) {

            var form = new Form({}, 'myForm');


            query("a.myLink").on("click", function () {

                var data = domForm.toObject(form.domNode);
                xhr.post("/echo/json", {
                    data: data // data to transfer
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log("Success");
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">

    <form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" id="myForm">
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <a class="myLink">Submit the form</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've a list of records and on the click event I edit different values of one record. And then I want to save the values to database by calling my spring controller.

Comment: Hi, the example I have provided you just tell you how to do that, basically call store.add() when you are saving your records. If you could provide me a jsfiddle with your code for your form, I can provide you a more detailed example on your actual implementation. Thanks.

Comment: but is it not possible to send a form with dojo without creating a store?

Comment: Yes, it is also possible to send information using a more direct api like for ajax. Please note, question was specifically on JsonRest :)

Comment: could you tell me how can I send it using dojo/request. I'm trying to send the entire form data as an object.

Comment: Yes, definitely, but please post your request as a separate question on SO including your form HTML markup. Please also considering accepting or up-voting my answer if you find it useful regarding your JsonRest question :) thanks!